# min and perfect forwarding

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, forwarding, rvalue-reference

The min algorithm is normally expressed like this:

```
template <typename T>
const T& min(const T& x, const T& y)
{
    return y < x ? y : x;
}
```

However, this does not allow constructs of the form `min(a, b) = 0`. You can achieve that with an additional overload:

```
template <typename T>
T& min(T& x, T& y)
{
    return y < x ? y : x;
}
```

What I would like to do is unify these two overloads via perfect forwarding:

```
template <typename T>
T&& min(T&& x, T&& y)
{
    return y < x ? std::forward<T>(y) : std::forward<T>(x);
}
```

However, g++ 4.5.0 spits out a warning for `min(2, 4)` that I return a reference to a temporary. Did I do something wrong?

---

Okay, I get it. The problem is with the conditional operator. In my first solution, if I call `min(2, 4)` the conditional operator sees an xvalue and thus moves from the forwarded `x` to produce a temporary object. Of course it would be dangerous to return that by reference! If I forward the whole expression instead of `x` and `y` seperately, the compiler does not complain anymore:

```
template <typename T>
T&& min(T&& x, T&& y)
{
    return std::forward<T>(y < x ? y : x);
}
```

---

Okay, I got rid of the references for arithmetic types :)

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type
min(T x, T y)
{
    return y < x ? y : x;
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T&&>::type
min(T&& x, T&& y)
{
    return std::forward<T>(y < x ? y : x);
}
```

Comment: Hmm it looks to me that the last example creates a temporary too according to the FCD. But this seems odd: It seems to create temporaries for binding a `int&&` to an `int` xvalue?! I thought that xvalues are anonymous rvalue refs that can be bound by rvalue references without having temporaries created? The same seems to happen for your revised code, doesn't it? The return type is `int&&`, and the return expression is an `int` xvalue. Why doesn't the compiler warn anymore for it?

Comment: If i read `8.5.3` correctly, it says that this creates an int temporary when binding the reference to the xvalue: `int x = 0; int &&rx = (int&&)x;` Likewise when using `std::move`. That can't be the intention, i think.

Comment: @Johannes: Which part of 8.5.3 are you talking about specifically?

Comment: @Fred all the rules :) This time, the very last bullet applies which creates a temporary.

Comment: @Johannes: In the middle of page 204, I find "Otherwise, if T2 is a class type and [...] the initializer expression is an rvalue [...] then the reference is bound to the initializer expression rvalue". No temporary objects necessary here.

Comment: `int` is not a class type. So for `int` a temporary is created. I think this is a defect.

Comment: @Johannes: Ah, I didn't see that. Yes, sounds like a defect to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you're trying to oversimplify the problem. Unfortunately, getting it entirely correct is decidedly non-trivial. If you haven't read [N2199](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2199.html), now would be a good time to do so. Rvalue references continue to evolve, so its reference implementation of min and max probably isn't exactly right anymore, but it should at least be a pretty decent starting point. Warning: the reference implementation is a *lot* more complex than you're going to like!

Comment: Looks like that proposal was rejected. Any idea why?

Comment: @jalf: I suspect people glanced at the reference implementation, and ran away screaming in terror. :-)

Comment: @jalf yep, see http://groups.google.de/group/comp.std.c++/browse_thread/thread/da71464ad690d506

Comment: "you're trying to oversimplify the problem" -> I prefer oversimplified problems to overcomplicated solutions :)

Comment: @FredOverflow: don't get me wrong -- I think just about everybody agrees that the "solution" presented in N2199 was/is excessively complex. OTOH, it's not overly complex just out of perversity -- though the paper wasn't accepted, the problem hasn't changed, and nothing has been added to the language to let a lot simpler solution do the same task. Essentially every simpler solution *will* have problems and shortcomings.

Comment: Agreed, but my intent was not to write the most general min function. All I wanted was to unify the two functions in my post via perfect forwarding to understand the technique better. Maybe I should have been clearer in my original post about my intentions.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want *perfect* forwarding, here, you want to return either `T&` or `const T&` and never `T&&`.  `std::forward` is designed for passing one of your parameters along to another function, not for return values.

I think what you want is:

```
template <typename T>
min(T&& x, T&& y) -> decltype(x)
{
    return y < x ? y : x;
}
```

EDIT to avoid dangling reference problem:

```
template <typename T>
struct dedangle { typedef T type; }

template <typename T>
struct dedangle<const T&> { typedef T type; }

template <typename T, typename U>
min(T&& x, U&& y) -> dedangle<decltype(0?y:x)>::type
{
    return y < x ? y : x;
}

// dedangle is re-usable by max, etc, so its cost is amortized
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure which type `decltype(x)` is, but it's either `T`, which is not at all what I want, or `T&&`, which is what you say I shouldn't do. Right?

Comment: Section 14.8.2.1 [temp.deduct.call] of the standard describes transformations that occur on the arguments of template functions.  `decltype(x)` could easily be `int&` or `const int&`, whereas the return type does not undergo this process.  Check out example #3 within that section of the standard.

Comment: I disagree, `decltype(x)` is always the same as `T&&`. You can convince yourself by inserting the line `static_assert(std::is_same<T&&, decltype(x)>::value, "ouch");` into the `min` function template.

Comment: So because the transformation is on `T`, not the argument `T&& x`, it does affect the return type after all?  What if you go ahead and return `T&&` but omit `std::forward`?

Comment: That won't work, because if I call `min(2, 4)`, then `T` is `int&&` and, due to reference collapsing rules, `T&&` is also `int&&`. So I would try to bind `int&&` to `y < x ? y : x` which is an lvalue (because both y and x are, like every formal parameter, lvalues), but rvalue references do not bind to lvalues.

Comment: If you call min(rval, rval) then T is the non-reference type U (where U is the type of the rvalue). The type of the parameters will be `U&&`. The type of the expression x will be lvalue of U, but since decltype(x) (non-parenthesized x) gets the type of the entity x instead of the expression x (for which it would yield `U&`), the decltype will be `U&&`. So min(2, 4) will return `int&&`. However, the type of the expressions y and x is lvalue of int, which can't be bound to `int&&`, and a compile time error will occur for the return. Thus your definition of min is wrong.

Comment: @Johannes: Are you addressing Ben or me?

Comment: @Johannes: Would it help to use `decltype((x))` or `decltype(0?y:x)` ?

Comment: @Fred i'm addressing whoever feels addressed. I was not addressing anyone in particular.

Comment: @Ben then the return type would be `U&` for non-const gl- or prvalues and `U const&` for const ones. I don't know what you want to archieve. In my opinion `min(1, 2)` should return `int` instead of a reference. Notice that you, aswell as @Fred version does not compile `int x = 0; min(1, x);` because of the inconsistent deduction for `T` on both parameters.

Comment: @Johannes: I agree, it would be better to handle arithmetic types without any references whatsoever, but getting rid of the templates mentally, I don't see any serious problems with `int&& min(int&& x, int&& y) { return std::forward<int>(y < x ? y : x); }`, except for the possibility to say `int&& x = min(1, 2);` where x is a dangling reference. But besides that, the solution is fine, isn't it?

Comment: @Fred: Does use of `auto` cause exactly that dangling reference problem?   @Johannes: `T&` and `const T&` are exactly what Fred asked for in the question.

Comment: @Ben: The dangling reference problem is caused by returning a reference, but I see no way around it here. The traditional C++98 `min` has the exact same problem.

Comment: @Fred: By using a helper template, it's easy to return values when the inputs are const references, and references when the inputs are non-const references.

Comment: @Ben: I know, playing with it right now :) BTW that's why I opened a topic on enable_if a couple of minutes ago :) Will post my code here as soon as I figured it out.

Comment: @Ben: Oh, you mean return values even for class types. No, that's too inefficient for me, I'd rather live with the dangling reference problem :) Personally, I have never bound an rvalue to a local reference variable...